# Black lines missing in the box holding the axes of a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

When plotting on a figure in MATLAB, I have noticed that parts of the black box that holds the axes are missing (the left and bottom one):

[image]

I have tried issuing:

```
box off
box on
```

commands with no success. Do you know what I can do to get the corresponding black lines on the axes?

### Note:

I am using the OpenGL renderer:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureRenderer','opengl');
```

Comment: Can you post the exact command used to generate this figure?

Comment: Have you used `alpha` function to set transparency? I've noticed that this command causes axes to disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have known issues with OpenGL renderer:

- [Why do the axes box and tick marks disappear when I use transparency in a plot in MATLAB 7.5 (R2007b)?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5TS5P4/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-5TS5P4)
- [Why does using PATCH with transparency cause the axes to disappear in MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-OAWEH/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-OAWEH)
- [Why does the ALPHA commmand make the top and right borders of my figure disappear in MATLAB R2011a (7.12)?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5X41G7/index.html)

Let us know what you did exactly to create this figure.

Comment: The problem was the `OpenGL renderer`. Thanks! I had this line: `set(0,'DefaultFigureRenderer','opengl');` in my `startup` file. I always thought OpenGL was better if your HW supports it. Is there any reason to **not** use it? (besides experimenting problems like the one I just did)

Comment: Have a look at this [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1200/1201.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the line width of the axes a bit:

```
set(gca, 'LineWidth', 1.2)
```

Also, switching from hardware (default) to software rendering may solve the problem:

```
opengl software
```

However, there may be drawbacks. Increasing the line width, e.g., changes all axes lines, including ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line of code to make the black lines appear

set(gca,'Layer','top')

Answer (score 0):

Being a perfectionist this bug bothered me for years! This is what seems to work, MATLAB R2013a:

1. I have OpenGL off (gives all kind of weird behavior): `set(0,'DefaultFigureRenderer','zbuffer')`
2. I add a box just before I plot something and right after I finish plotting:

   ```
   axes(handles.MyAxes);

   cla;

   hold off;  
   box on;
   hold on;

   % Do your plotting...
   % scatter(...);
   % plot(...);
   % ...

   box on;
   ```
3. I also noticed that if the first command is `plot` then the bug may still be present. In this case I plot just a single point using `scatter` with white color (makes it invisible) and then use `plot`. That is, `scatter(x(1),y(1),1,'MarkerEdgeColor','w','MarkerFaceColor','w')` and then `plot(x,y,...)`.

My answer in fact refers to **missing box lines when plotting in a GUIDE figure**. I never had this issue when using a regular `figure()` and then `plot(...)` commands.

Hope it helps!