# Matlab - highlight a specific interval using patch

Tags: matlab, highlight

I would like to highlight a specific interval in my plot. I found a way using the patch object.
The problem is that my layout gets messy whenever i use it.

Here's an example of a plot:

```
x = 1:0.05:25;
plot(x,sin(x)+sin(100*x)/3);
xlabel('x axis');
ylabel('y axis');
title('\Omega \Delta test');
legend('sin \Sigma')
```

And to highlight a period:

```
yl = ylim;
patch([5 5 10 10],[yl(1) yl(2) yl(2) yl(1)],'k',...
    'facecolor',[.4 .6 .4],'edgecolor',[.4 .6 .4],...
    'facealpha',0.3,'edgealpha',0.3)
```

My results with and without the patch command:

Normal:

[image: normal plot]

Messy:

[image: messy plot with transparency]

Look at the fonts and the legend block.  Any ideas on how to fix that?

Is there a better way to highlight an interval? I need to choose the color and set transparency.

Just one more question: Why do I have to use the third input (color) if it's not applied?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the OpenGL renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**Edit:** This answer is only valid for Matlab versions before 2014b, as the incredibly useful `erasemode` property has been removed from all HG2 graphic objects on later Matlab versions.</sub>

---

I ran into this problem countless times and I had to learn to live with it. Most times I can accept the glitches of the `OpenGL` renderer if it buys me nice transparency effects, but in some cases it is just not acceptable.

I use `patch` objects to highlight intervals in many applications, usually over several curves. There is a trick you can use when transparency is not an option, it is the `EraseMode` property of the patch object. If you set the `EraseMode` property to `'xor'` the patch will not be transparent, yet anything under the patch will `xor` the patch pixel colours so you can still see the curves under the patch.

This not being a transparency rendering, you can use the default `painter` renderer and avoid all the occasional glitches of the `OpenGL`.

So for example with your data:

```
hp = patch([5 5 10 10],[yl(1) yl(2) yl(2) yl(1)],'k',...
    'facecolor','g','edgecolor','g',...
    'erasemode','xor') ;
```

[image: green patch]

---

And the nice advantage of this trick is it works with monochrome display/prints. If you cannot use multiple colours, you can use that with only one colour (if you plan black & white printing for publication for example)

```
hpx = patch([5 5 10 10],[yl(1) yl(2) yl(2) yl(1)],'b',...
    'facecolor','b','edgecolor','b',...
    'erasemode','xor') ;
```

[image: reverse patch]

Comment: Thank you! This will certainly help me. I found a way to keep the original colors switching the plot order so the lines lie over the patch ( 'set(gca,'children',flipud(get(gca,'children')))' ). Don't know if it is a good ideia for complex and more elaborate plot.

Comment: @AlexandreM. Changing the plot order is also a valid solution. If you go this way and your plots get more complex, I suggest retrieving the plot handle as you create them, and use the function [`uistack`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html)

Answer (score 2):

(Note: This answer only makes sense if you're using the OpenGL renderer.)

If that's the case, then this is one symptom of

> a bug in MATLAB 6.5 (R13) and later versions in the way that axes are rendered in hardware accelerated OpenGL, when transparency is used

as mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101588-why-does-using-patch-with-transparency-cause-the-axes-to-disappear-in-matlab).

The simplest workaround is to force OpenGL to run in software mode by including the line:

```
opengl software
```

[Apparently](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94338-why-does-the-alpha-function-make-the-left-and-bottom-borders-of-my-figure-disappear-in-matlab), this only works under Windows and Linux. For other symptoms of the problem and different approaches to solutions have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775020/black-lines-missing-in-the-box-holding-the-axes-of-a-matlab-plot).

Regarding your other questions:

Not sure if it's a better way, but it's another option: You could use an `area`-plot like this:

```
opengl software
figure

x = 1:0.05:25;
ax = plot(x,sin(x)+sin(100*x)/3);

hold on
basevalue = -2;
areaAx = area([5,10],[2,2], basevalue);
set(areaAx, 'FaceColor', [.4 .6 .4])
alpha = get(areaAx, 'Children');
%make area plot transparent
set(alpha, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
set(areaAx, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

xlabel('x axis');
ylabel('y axis');
title('\Omega \Delta test');
legend('sin \Sigma')

xlim('auto')
ylim('auto')
hold off
```

However, OpenGL renderer will also cause problems here, so it's not a fix, just another option.

And finally, I'm not sure what you mean by the color not being used. The `'facecolor'` is used, that's why your plot is green. When you go through the `area`-option above step by step you'll see that you get a solid color first. Later on, transparency is added with the `'facealpha'`-option.

Comment: Good to know that there is another option. When i use <code>'opengl software'</code> it keeps the axes box, already looks better. Thank you!